# How do I perform a Datomic transaction using the entity id of an enum / ref?

Tags: clojure, enums, ref, datomic

I'm attempting to insert a new entity into my Datomic database with references to enum / ref types that I've created (`:client/gender` and `:client/referral`).

The schema entry to the `:client/referral` type looks like this (and the `:client/gender` definition is almost identical):

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
  :db/ident :client/referral
  :db/valueType :db.type/ref
  :db/cardinality :db.cardinality/one
  :db/doc "The referral source for this client"
  :db.install/_attribute :db.part/db
  }

[:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :client.referral/friend]
[:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :client.referral/online]
[:db/add #db/id[:db.part/user] :db/ident :client.referral/radio]
```

The transaction function looks something like this (I've tried all kinds of variations on it):

```
(defn add-client [client]
  (let [gender (:gender client)
        referral (:referral client)]
    @(d/transact conn
      [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
       :client/name (:name client)
       :client/phone (:phone client)
       :client/email (:email client)
       :client/date-of-birth (:dateOfBirth client)
       :client/gender gender
       :client/referral referral}])))
```

This particular variation produces the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: :db.error/not-an-entity Unable to resolve entity: 17592186045422 in datom [#db/id[:db.part/user -1000022] :client/gender "17592186045422"]
              ...
Caused by: datomic.impl.Exceptions$IllegalArgumentExceptionInfo: :db.error/not-an-entity Unable to resolve entity: 17592186045422 in datom [#db/id[:db.part/user -1000022] :client/gender "17592186045422"]
                error.clj:57 datomic.error/arg
                error.clj:55 datomic.error/arg
                  db.clj:555 datomic.db/require-id
                 db.clj:2334 datomic.db/datomic.db.ProcessInpoint
                 db.clj:2317 datomic.db/datomic.db.ProcessInpoint
                 db.clj:2512 datomic.db/with-tx[fn]
   PersistentVector.java:333 clojure.lang.PersistentVector.reduce
               core.clj:6518 clojure.core/reduce
                 db.clj:2512 datomic.db/with-tx[fn]
                 db.clj:2516 datomic.db/with-tx
                peer.clj:558 datomic.peer.LocalConnection/fn
                peer.clj:558 datomic.peer/datomic.peer.LocalConnection
                peer.clj:550 datomic.peer/datomic.peer.LocalConnection
                  api.clj:94 datomic.api/transact
                   ...
```

I've also tried variations like this (among other things) but to no avail:

```
@(d/transact conn
      [{:db/id (d/tempid :db.part/user)
       :client/name (:name client)
       :client/phone (:phone client)
       :client/email (:email client)
       :client/date-of-birth (:dateOfBirth client)
       :client/gender #db/id[:db.user/part gender]
       :client/referral #db/id[:db.user/part referral]}])
```

What, probably obvious, thing am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I switched to using :db/ident for the reference types and it resolved the issue.

```
@(d/transact conn
           [{:db/id                (d/tempid :db.part/user)
             :client/name          (:name client)
             :client/phone         (:phone client)
             :client/email         (:email client)
             :client/date-of-birth (:dateOfBirth client)
             :client/gender        {:db/ident (:gender client)}
             :client/referral      {:db/ident (:referral client)}}])
```

Comment: The solution you stumbled upon doesn't actually address the underlying error. It's misleading to leave it up as accepted. The answer that refers to the "string in value position" provides the correct analysis.

Comment: it seems to me this is a bug in the way Datomic expands the transaction request into Datoms, I'm getting bitten by the same thing. At least the provided answer gives a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Your input data is the error source. Observe the string in the value position of the datom reported in the exception thrown.

> [#db/id[:db.part/user -1000022] :client/gender "17592186045422"]

It should be the entity ID of a gender entity or a keyword identifiying it via :db/ident.

Make sure your transaction reads something like this:

```
[:db/add (d/tempid :db.part/user) :client/gender :gender/male]
```

(Assuming that you have an entity with `:db/ident :gender/male`)

(Side note: Your avatar image, the Clojure logo, is copyrighted I believe)